# Как можно отследить загрузку IFormFile файла клиентом, в форме

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Я вешаю атрибут Required, на свойство, но отслеживается загрузка, для всего экземпляра, не проверяя его дочерние.

Я читал что для IEnumerable типов и "листов" такой атрибут не применим, но как тогда решается данная задача, как бы вы сделали, думаю не мало людей сталкивалось с загрузкой нескольких файлов.

Есть вот такая модель представления

```
public class NoLoadedDocType
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Файл не выбран, загрузите файл!")]
        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        public List<IFormFile> FormFile { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public List<DocumentType> DocumentType { get; set; }
    }
```

Это представление

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.DocumentType.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">@Model.DocumentType[i].Description </label>
                <label class='col control-label' style='color: #E17F00'>@Model.DocumentType[i].ImportantDescription</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input asp-for=@Model.FormFile class="form-control" style="max-width: 100%;" type="file" />
                    <span asp-validation-for=@Model.FormFile></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Поищите в NuGet или утащите с гитхаба какой-нибудь готовый загрузчик. Их много всяких придумано. Ну а если просто погуглить, то вот [первая попавшаяся ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54724664/12888024).

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Решил добавлением атрибута required в самом инпуте загружаемого файла.